# Python: parsing structured CSV file to dict

Tags: python, csv

Is there any idea to parse the multiple lines structured csv like as:

```
H3|509596|OUT|1653128|06/11/2018|
D1|1653128|1|390|MXT586|EA|EA|55.600|219.99|Product 1
D2|1653128|1|900|390|
T1|1653128|999|1000.000|
H3|509597|OUT|1653128|06/11/2018|
D1|1653128|1|390|MXT586|EA|EA|55.600|219.99|Product 2
D2|1653128|1|900|390|
D2|1653128|2|600|430|
T1|1653128|999|2164.000|
```

- H3 = Header (1 - n times in file)
- D1 = Line Item (1 - 999 times)
- D2 = Line Sub Item of D1 (0 - 999 times)
- T1 = Trailer (1 - n times in file)

I want to read the content and parse to dict list like as:

```
List of Dict: 
 [ (
     Header : (509596, 'OUT', 1653128, '06/11/2018')
     Items  : [ (1653128, 1, 390, 'MXT586', 'EA', 'EA', ....,
                  (1, 900, 390) ) ]
     Trailer: (1653128, 999, 1000)
    ), ...
 ]
```

Comment: There seems to be no `T3`, and how should the dictionary look?

Comment: Yes there is, what have you tried so far and where did you get stuck? Also, how do you imagine your dictionary would look like based on the data (what would be the keys and what would be their values)?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please take the [tour], and visit the [help].  Particularly, please read [ask], because as your question stands right now, the answer to your question is "Yes, I have some ideas."  It would help if the question had more details and some code, that way people know what level to help you at, and the next person who comes with a problem similar to yours would have a chance of finding your question and its answers.

Comment: Your question implies, but doesn't specifically state:  under each `H3`, you can have ... 0-many?  1-many?  `D1` lines.  And under each `D1` you can have ... 0-many?  1-many?  `D2` lines.  And there's only one Header and one Trailer per set?

Comment: Sorry, the question is edited.

Answer (score 0):

Python's `csv` library can read that file by specifying a `|` as the delimiter. Some care is needed to remove any empty trailing entries as some of the lines have a `|` at the end.

```
import csv

def get_int(v):
    # Attempt to convert the value into an integer
    try:
        return int(v)
    except ValueError as e:
        return v    # Return the original value

filter_na = lambda row: tuple(get_int(v) for v in row[1:] if v)
data = []

with open('input.csv') as f_input:
    csv_input = csv.reader(f_input, delimiter='|')
    block = {}

    for row in csv_input:
        if row[0] == 'H3':
            block['Header'] = filter_na(row)
        elif row[0].startswith('D'):
            try:
                block['Items'].append(filter_na(row))
            except KeyError:
                block['Items'] = [filter_na(row)]
        elif row[0] == 'T1':
                block['Trailer'] = filter_na(row)
                data.append(block)

    print(data)
```

This would give you a list of dictionaries looking like:

```
[
    {
        'Header': (509597, 'OUT', 1653128, '06/11/2018'), 
        'Items': [(1653128, 1, 390, 'MXT586', 'EA', 'EA', '55.600', '219.99', 'Product 1'), (1653128, 1, 900, 390), (1653128, 1, 390, 'MXT586', 'EA', 'EA', '55.600', '219.99', 'Product 2'), (1653128, 1, 900, 390), (1653128, 2, 600, 430)], 
        'Trailer': (1653128, 999, '2164.000')
    }, 
    {
        'Header': (509597, 'OUT', 1653128, '06/11/2018'), 
        'Items': [(1653128, 1, 390, 'MXT586', 'EA', 'EA', '55.600', '219.99', 'Product 1'), (1653128, 1, 900, 390), (1653128, 1, 390, 'MXT586', 'EA', 'EA', '55.600', '219.99', 'Product 2'), (1653128, 1, 900, 390), (1653128, 2, 600, 430)], 
        'Trailer': (1653128, 999, '2164.000')
    }
]
```